# Magento 2: Coupon code makes an order free

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.1, coupon-codes

I have a Magento 2.3.1 that makes this problem:

I have a coupon code that makes 90 EUR discount defined as:

[image]

1. Add a product to cart of 70 EUR (below 90 EUR)
2. Goto to cart, apply the coupon code
3. Total is 0 in cart
4. Add another product of price 120 EUR
5. Cart total is 190 EUR (above 90 EUR)
6. I *still* get the total of 0 EUR in cart

Why is this?

Comment: "i have a coupon code that makes 90 EUR discount" - can you show the settings for this please? it would be crucial to providing help

Comment: sure, https://imgur.com/a/Gu0X5O9 , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 2 options for cart rule for fixed amount

- Fixed amount discount - It applies per product
- Fixed amount discount for whole cart - It applies for whole cart

So make sure you have selected 2nd options not 1st option.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will apply this discount to all items in the basket, to prevent this I would advise you set

`Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To` to 1 and `Discard Subsequent Rules` to Yes and this might solve your problem.

However there are several issues with the cart price rules where you need to lock down the products that this applies to or [describe the conditions](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-create.html#step-2-describe-the-conditions) more accurately that prevent the rule matching - where at present you have no conditions so this rule will always match.